# How to add dependencies for Room in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm following an official tutorial to use Room for data persistence in Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-practice-bus-schedule-app

When adding the dependencies as instructued I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to find method ''org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinAndroidTarget org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation.getTarget()''
'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinAndroidTarget org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation.getTarget()'
```

My app `build.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin")

    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.21-1.0.11"

}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.sweatsink"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.sweatsink"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    //Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.0")
}
```

I don't know much about Android development so hopefully someone knows why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `version`.

```
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.21-1.0.11"
```

to

```
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.10-1.0.13"
```

Comment: I did that, I'm now getting this error when trying to run the app: Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmCompilerOptionsHelper'.